# How to sort values in one column ascending and another column descending

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns. I'm trying to sort one column ('values') by descending order, and when two values are the same, sort another column by ascending order. Currently, my code is:

```
br_df = br_imgfeatures_df.mean().reset_index(name='value').sort_values(by='value', ascending=False)
```

Which is producing this output:

[image]

As you can see, the values for 'Palm trees' and 'Flowers' are the same, but I'm trying to reorder them with 'Flowers' on top of 'Palm trees'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.DataFrame.sort_values) accepts lists for the `by` parameter, you can use the code below and replace `Column_X` by the name of the first/other column :

```
br_df = (
            br_imgfeatures_df.mean()
                .reset_index(name='value')
                .sort_values(by=['value', 'Column_X'],
                             ascending=[False, True])
        )
```

##### # Output :

```
     Column_X     value
0   Nighttime  0.031496
1     Flowers  0.023622
2  Palm trees  0.023622
3       Cliff  0.020997
4      Bridge  0.018373
```